how to run termux command in another app?
I need to launch script in termux in java (i want to make apk compiler). Here is build_script.sh file:
#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/sh

# Додайте PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin

echo "=== Starting script ==="

pkg update -y
pkg upgrade -y
pkg install -y openjdk-17 dx ecj aapt apksigner termux-api

echo "=== Packages installed ==="

# Параметри
APP_NAME=$1
PACKAGE_NAME=$2
MAIN_ACTIVITY=$3
SOURCE_DIR=$4
BUILD_DIR=$5
OUTPUT_DIR=$6
MANIFEST_FILE="AndroidManifest.xml"
MAIN_ACTIVITY_CODE="
package $PACKAGE_NAME;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class $MAIN_ACTIVITY extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Тут можна додати ваш код
    }
}
"

echo "=== Parameters set ==="

MANIFEST_CONTENT="
<manifest xmlns:android=\"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android\"
    package=\"$PACKAGE_NAME\">
    <application
        android:allowBackup=\"true\"
        android:icon=\"@mipmap/ic_launcher\"
        android:label=\"$APP_NAME\"
        android:roundIcon=\"@mipmap/ic_launcher_round\"
        android:supportsRtl=\"true\"
        android:theme=\"@style/Theme.MyApp\">
        <activity android:name=\".$MAIN_ACTIVITY\">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=\"android.intent.action.MAIN\" />
                <category android:name=\"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER\" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
"

# Створення необхідних директорій
mkdir -p $SOURCE_DIR/$PACKAGE_NAME
mkdir -p $BUILD_DIR
mkdir -p $OUTPUT_DIR
mkdir -p res/mipmap

echo "=== Directories created ==="

# Створення основного Java файлу
echo "$MAIN_ACTIVITY_CODE" > $SOURCE_DIR/$PACKAGE_NAME/$MAIN_ACTIVITY.java

# Створення AndroidManifest.xml
echo "$MANIFEST_CONTENT" > $MANIFEST_FILE

# Створення placeholder іконок
touch res/mipmap/ic_launcher.png
touch res/mipmap/ic_launcher_round.png

echo "=== Files created ==="

# Перевірка наявності файлів
echo "=== Checking files ==="
ls -R $SOURCE_DIR
ls -R res
cat $MANIFEST_FILE

# Компіляція Java-коду
find $SOURCE_DIR -name "*.java" > sources.txt
ecj -d $BUILD_DIR @sources.txt
if [ $? -ne 0 ];то echo "Помилка компіляції Java файлів"
    then exit 1
fi

# Перетворення класів в DEX файл
dx --dex --output=$BUILD_DIR/classes.dex $BUILD_DIR
if [ $? -ne 0 ];то echo "Помилка перетворення класів в DEX файл"
   then exit 1
fi

# Створення APK файлу
aapt package -f -m -F $OUTPUT_DIR/$APP_NAME.unsigned.apk -M $MANIFEST_FILE -S res -I $PREFIX/share/aapt/android.jar
if [ $? -ne 0 ];то echo "Помилка створення APK файлу"
    then exit 1
fi

# Додавання DEX файлу в APK
aapt add $OUTPUT_DIR/$APP_NAME.unsigned.apk $BUILD_DIR/classes.dex
if [ $? -ne 0 ];то echo "Помилка додавання DEX файлу в APK"
    then exit 1
fi

# Підписання APK
apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.jks --out $OUTPUT_DIR/$APP_NAME.apk $OUTPUT_DIR/$APP_NAME.unsigned.apk
if [ $? -ne 0 ];то echo "Помилка підписання APK файлу"
   then exit 1
fi

# Очищення
rm sources.txt
rm -rf $BUILD_DIR

echo "APK створено: $OUTPUT_DIR/$APP_NAME.apk"

Also made Java methods to run code:
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 123;
    public static final String SCRIPT_NAME = "build_script.sh";
............
    private void runTermuxCommand() {
        try {
            // Шлях до скопійованого скрипта
            File scriptFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), SCRIPT_NAME);

            // Додати права на виконання скрипта
            scriptFile.setExecutable(true);

            // Параметри для скрипта
            String appName = "MyApp";
            String packageName = "com.example.myapp";
            String mainActivity = "MainActivity";
            String sourceDir = "src";
            String buildDir = "build";
            String outputDir = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/GenCoreLite";

            // Команда для виконання скрипта з параметрами
            String command = String.format(
                    "sh %s %s %s %s %s %s %s",
                    scriptFile.getAbsolutePath(), appName, packageName, mainActivity, sourceDir, buildDir, outputDir
            );

            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh", "-c", command});

            // Отримати вивід
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            // Отримати помилки
            BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            StringBuilder errorOutput = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = errorReader.readLine()) != null) {
                errorOutput.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            // Дочекатися завершення процесу
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();

            // Показати вивід та помилки
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                editor.setText("Output:\n" + output.toString() + "\nErrors:\n" + errorOutput.toString());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Termux command finished with exit code: " + exitCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TermuxCommand", "Error running Termux command", e);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error running Termux command: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                runTermuxCommand();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    private void copyScriptToStorage() throws Exception {
        // Copy the script from assets to internal storage
        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(SCRIPT_NAME);
        File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), SCRIPT_NAME);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }

}
................
compile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    copyScriptToStorage();
                    runTermuxCommand();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TermuxCommand", "Error copying or running Termux command", e);
                }
            }
        });


Also i added permissions into androiManifest:
    <uses-permission android:name="com.termux.permission.RUN_COMMAND" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.termux.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.termux.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

In this case i added perms for termux (for package com.termux) and my app can run termux command from my app:

`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ccs.gencorelite/files/build_script.sh[8]: pkg: inaccessible or not found
I/System.out: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ccs.gencorelite/files/build_script.sh[9]: pkg: inaccessible or not found
I/System.out: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ccs.gencorelite/files/build_script.sh[10]: pkg: inaccessible or not found
...............
`
So, i have troubles with some parts of commands that is have not perms and command didnt find, what trouble with?

What do you mean by "I added perms for Termux"? No matter what you do the app private data (this includes all the Termux commands) are not accessible from other apps. That is a core concept of Android.

@Robert, i granted permissions for my app and i added screen how this permission looks like, so i thing that my app can run commands in termux in app's enviroment

I would recommend to you reading the documentation what those Termux permissions allow you to do, e.g. RUN_COMMAND. They work totally different as you expect: you have to create an Intent to execute a command.
